# Break loop if false

Tags: vba, excel

I will have a set of data on Excel that a user will press a button and it will be appended on an SQL Table. This will only happen only and only if a validation column (say column C) is all `true`.

If there is a single `false` in the validation column, then the code should stop and the sql statement will not be executed.

Example, table below should be allow SQL code to be executed and have it appended on SQL Table:

```
Name    Age Validation
John    25  TRUE
Jane    33  TRUE
Eniola  39  TRUE
Alex    23  TRUE
Dave    22  TRUE
Tom     30  TRUE
Kat     23  TRUE
Kim     37  TRUE
```

And table below should not be executed as there is a `false` on validation column:

```
Name    Age Validation
John    25  TRUE
Jane    33  TRUE
Eniola  39  TRUE
Jon     42  FALSE
Dave    22  TRUE
Tom     30  TRUE
Kat     23  TRUE
Kim     37  TRUE
```

To do this, I think the most efficient way is to set up a `For Loop` to go through column C to check all values are `true`.

I have attempted to do this using code below:

```
    Dim i as Long
    For i = 1 to Rows.count
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
    msgbox("unable to execute")
    End If
    Next i
    ------ code to execute SQL command -------
```

I am not sure how to break code if there is a `false` in a column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 1 to Rows.count
     If Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
          msgbox("unable to execute")
          GoTo FailedCheck
     End If
Next i

'execute sql

FailedCheck:

'Code resume here without running sql
```

Its important to note that using this method, while powerful, can be dangerous at times. Try to avoid using it. Could be rewritten like this

```
Dim i as Long, chk as boolean
chk = True
For i = 1 to Rows.count
     If Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
          msgbox("unable to execute")
          chk = False
          Exit For
     End If
Next i

If chk = true Then 'execute sql
```

Answer (score 4):

You need an `Exit For`:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
        MsgBox ("unable to execute")
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

**Update after comment**

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = False Then
        MsgBox ("unable to execute")
        Exit For
    Else
        ' Do the sql command here, if you want it once per row until a False if found
    End If
Next i
' Do the sql command here if you only run it once after the loop
```

Comment: If I use this, this means I will need to place the SQL command within the For and after the IF, correct?

Comment: That depends on how you create your SQL command. It is one call per Excel row, then inside the for loop, as an `Else`. If it is after the loop, then it is after the loop.

Comment: Sorry - I mean the whole point is to break the loop and not execute SQL command if there is a false. Therefore it must be within the For loop, right?